# I want to select the 'displayImage~' from linkedin api response

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I recently started playing around with the linkedin v2 api .I am trying to get the profile image url after sucessfull authentication

I sent a request to this end point [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=${accessToken}](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage%7E:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

and get the users information containing the profile image details

i am having problem selecting the secound 'displayImage~' field from the response.

```
{
  profilePicture: {
    displayImage: 'urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:CgiiriBq9LJg8yRQ',
    'displayImage~': { paging: [Object], elements: [Array] }
  },
  id: 'linkedin_id'
}
```

below is a copy of my code

```
  getProfilePic(accessToken) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=${accessToken}`;
      request.get({ url: url }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return reject(err);
        }
        // const { id, localizedFirstName, localizedLastName, } = body localizedFirstName
        let data = JSON.parse(body);
        imgDetails = data.displayImage~
        return resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the way the data was arranged inside of the array,i used lodash to select the profile image link

```
let url = _.pick(val, 'displayImage~')["displayImage~"].elements[1].identifiers[0].identifier;
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this format, it works like magic. Do not parse the response else you will run into errors.

```
getProfilePic(accessToken) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))&oauth2_access_token=${accessToken}`;
      request.get({ url: url }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return reject(err);
        }
        // const { id, localizedFirstName, localizedLastName, } = body localizedFirstName
        let data = body.data.profilePicture["displayImage~"].elements[3].identifiers[0].identifier
        return resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```